# Database design for academic quiz app

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I want to make a quiz app with many subjects such as math, biology, physics, chemistry, etc.

Is it good that I make a table for each subject, or should I just add a column named 'subject' in a table 'problems' ?

Which one is the best for performance?

Comment: If the only extra column is `subject` then add the column and use it as a reference to the table holding the actual subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, in your case, I will create a table named `subjects` which stores all your subjects, and then a column `subject` in your `problems` table in order to create a `foreign key` between these two tables.

In this way, you can easily add some specific parameters for your subjects (as the difficulty) and retrieve these parameters easily as well.

Good luck for your new project!

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, do you know the best way to retrieve random problems from the `problems` table? I mean like, I just want 30 random problems in 50 newest records. Is it better using SQL query rand() or retrieve the 50 newest records and then picks 30 of it randomly using PHP? Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for the best performance, you have to get the 30 random problems you need with a SQL request. It's always faster to get the data directly from the database with a `LIMIT`, instead of getting all the results for dealing with them later in PHP.
Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it's the case. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your logical data-model to be one table with a subject (with a separate linked table to list your subjects).
From a performance point of view when you come to build it, unless the number of rows is vast then I wouldn't expect that you'd need to compromise the design (assuming you are using a mature database technology like SQL).